# Change TinyMce Height of Elementor's widget

Tags: css, tinymce, elementor

In Elementor, i would like to change all TinyMce height.
I try in CSS but it doesnt work even my CSS is loaded.

```
.mce-container > iframe {
height: 100px !important;}
```

I don't find any documentation about this.
Any idea ?